# texdoc error: /usr/bin/env: ‘texlua’: No such file or directory

Tags: texdoc

I just did a fresh installation of texlive 2023 and modified PATH on my Linux machine, and I had

```
zjs@manjaro ~]$ which texdoc
/home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texdoc
[zjs@manjaro ~]$ texdoc
/usr/bin/env: ‘texlua’: No such file or directory
[zjs@manjaro ~]$ which texlua
/home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texlua
```

Comment: what does`file /home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texlua` report? my guess would be `broken link`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `file /home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texlua` reports `/home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/texlua: symbolic link to luatex` and `which luatex` reports `/home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/luatex`.

Comment: hmm sometimes guesses are wrong.  so do `luatex  --version` and `texlua --version` both work as commands?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, both work.

Comment: sorry I can't guess more from here, perhaps contact  the maintainers who may be able to trace where it is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the cause is using ~ in PATH.

Before: `export PATH="$PATH:~/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux"`

After: `export PATH="$PATH:/home/zjs/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux"`